# Heroku Cannot find module

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm trying to require some JS file in Node,
Localy - works great, but in Heroku I get this error-

> Error: Cannot find module './routes.js'

my code looks like :

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// Application Header
app.use(function(request, response, next) {
    response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With, X-PINGOTHER');

  next();
});

// views is directory for all template files
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

  console.log('./routes.js');
require('./routes.js')(app);

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanx!

Comment: Are you sure you did commit this file? Because the code looks good to me.

Comment: Does the file exist on Heroku? first: `heroku run bash` then: `cat routes.js` to see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try running a one-off copy of your dyno to have it list the directory contents – this would allow you to check if your file is where you'd expect it to be. (Heroku has more information on this [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#an-example-one-off-dyno).) For example:

`heroku run 'ls -al'`

This will cause Heroku to create (very briefly) an additional copy of your application, and have it list the files in your app's directory on the server. You may find that your `routes.js` file is not where you expect it to be. (Perhaps it's not checked into git?)

If you'd like to poke around further, run:

`heroku run bash`

And you'll have an interactive bash shell to a copy of your app. From there you can poke around at the filesystem, try running your app manually on the server, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Try to disable the Heroku build cache to recreate the `node_modules` directory.

With the [Heroku CLI](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) installed, write:

```
$ heroku config:set NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false
$ git commit -am 'disable_node_modules_cache' --allow-empty
$ git push heroku master
```

As described [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#cache-behavior).

Answer (score 0):

you're missing the `__dirname` that you have everywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this. I changed my DB directory to lowercase and for some reason this change didn't push up to github. So in Heroku it could not read the path where the db stuff was located as it's case sensitive it seems.