# Why is this error coming up? "Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "/app/views""

Tags: angularjs, node.js, heroku, express

I am trying to deploy my angular app to heroku. It runs fine locally.

Directory:

```
nice-notes
 controllers
  api.js
  index.js
 Model
  model.js
 public
  main.js
  main.css
 views
  index.jade
  layout.jade
  payment.jade
app.js
package.json
Procfile
node_modules
```

My app.js looks like so:

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.get('/', indexController.index);
app.get('/payment', indexController.payment);


app.get('/api/notes', apiController.get);
app.post('/api/notes', apiController.noteUpdate);
```

My controller:

```
var Note = require('../Model/model')

var indexController = {    
    index: function(req, res) {
        res.render('index');
    }, 
    payment: function(req, res) {
        res.render('payment');
    } 
}


module.exports = indexController;
```

I have tried using this instead, but 'path' is not defined.

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

All my base code is identical to my other angular apps, apart from the fact that I'm not injecting any templates here (using ng-view).

I have tried changing the file paths and other potential solutions to no avail.

Comment: did you define path in your main file `var path = require("path");` ? if not then, install path using npm like `npm install path`

Comment: I tried this and am still getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had changed some filenames (capitalising the first letter), and then changed it back, but it never logged it.

Typing

```
heroku run 'ls -al'
```

into the shell creates a one-off dyno and displays the file-system as heroku sees it.

This is the thread that solved my problem:

[Heroku Cannot find module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31214997/heroku-cannot-find-module)