# Heroku cannot find any module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, heroku

I'm trying to develop a webapp using meteor and Heroku. When I run my code locally everything is fine, but as soon as I deploy it on Heroku, i get:

> Cannot find module './navbar/NavBar.js'

or if I get rid of the NavBar in my code:

> Cannot find module './component/App'

My project folder looks like:

```
project
  client
    main.css
    main.html
    main.js
      component
        App.js
        Games.js
        Home.js
        Workbench.js
        navbar
          NavBar.js

  Server
    main.js
```

And this is my code:

main.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import App from './component/App';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

});
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Container} from 'reactstrap';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

import Workbench from './Workbench'
import NavBar from './navbar/NavBar.js'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <Router>
        <div>
        <NavBar/>
          <Container fluid={true}>
            <Route path='/' component={Workbench}/>
          </Container>
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

NavBar.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {nav} from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class NavBar extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      gameList: [{}],
      gamesVisibility: false
    }
  }
  render() {
    const {gameList, gameVisibility} = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="sidenav">
          <h2 className="sidenav-header"><a href="/">Test project</a></h2>
          <ul>
            <li onClick={() => this.setState({gameVisibility: !gameVisibility})}> <a className="SideNavTitle">Games</a> {this.renderArrow(gameVisibility)} </li>
              {this.renderCollection(gameVisibility, gameList)}
            <li className="SideNavItem"><a>Channel</a></li>
            <li className="SideNavItem"><a>About</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }

  renderCollection(visibility, collection){
      if (visibility){
          return collection.map((game) => <li id = 'test' className="SideNavSubItem"><a>{game.name}</a></li>)
      }
      else{
        return;
      }
  }

  renderArrow(visibility){
    if (visibility){
      return <i className="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true" style={{color: 'white'}}/>
    }
    else{
      return <i className="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true" style={{color: 'white'}}/>
    }
  }

}
```

I used `heroku run bash` along with `cat NavBar.js` to confirm that my file was on heroku as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31214997/heroku-cannot-find-module) post. Its kind of weird since the code work perfectly locally

Edit: The build on Heroku is successful, these errors show when I try to load my page.

Comment: Which Heroku buildpack are you using to deploy your Meteor project?

Comment: I've followed this tutorial: https://medium.com/@leonardykris/how-to-run-a-meteor-js-application-on-heroku-in-10-steps-7aceb12de234

So my buildpack is: https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse.git

Answer (score 0):

With some searching, I found that on heroku, I had a Component folder and a component folder. Not sure why since there is only 1 folder component in my meteor project. Used `heroku run bash` to find what was my problem.

Answer (score -1):

> I am assuming your project folder contains three sub folders(client,component, server).  In your main.js file use:

`import App from '../component/App'`

> you are using single "." which searches the component folder in server folder. 
>   you need to traverse back with double "."

Comment: Is the issue remains same ? @Gleyak iHope

Comment: I have 2 sub folders ( Client and server ) Component is a sub folder of client. I still tried your solution since I'm so lost and everything can only help but it didnt work. As I said, my project works perfectly in local so I'm pretty sure my code is alright. Thanks for trying tho! :)