# Why cant heroku find my node modules when deploying?

Tags: node.js, heroku

When I deploy I get the error Cannot find module '../../models/User' but my 
solution works fine locally. here is a pic of my console [console log of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rviat.jpg) and a link to the repo https://github.com/No-MyNameIs/trashalbums

I understand similar questions have been presented and I worked through those solutions before presented and I tried working through those below with no luck.  Any help would be appreciated.
[Heroku deploy Error: Cannot find module - compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51939876/heroku-deploy-error-cannot-find-module-compilation) 
[Heroku Cannot find module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31214997/heroku-cannot-find-module)
[console log of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rviat.jpg)

Comment: In your package .json I don't see any engine section.  Can you add a engine section as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51939876/heroku-deploy-error-cannot-find-module-compilation

Comment: that worked mandem. @SuleymanSah. thanks.

Comment: Can I add this as an asnwer, if you accept?

Comment: yes. I'm new here. how do i accept? @SuleymanSah

Comment: Ok I added my answer, to accept it  click the "check mark" button underneath the vote buttons

Comment: as described here 
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of Node.js that will be used to run your application on Heroku, should also be defined in engines section of your package.json file.

For example:

```
"engines": {
    "node": "11.0.0",
},
```

docs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs#specify-the-version-of-node